# Python Nose html report can it be run through Pycharm IDE

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nose

I use the following command from windows cmd prompt to run my Selenium Python Test Script.

```
nosetests.exe e:\test_runners\selenium_regression_test\ClearCore\Regression TestCase\RegressionProject_TestCase2.py --with-html --html-file=e:\report.html
```

Can this nose command be run through the PyCharm IDE or in the main part of the test script?

E.g. through here:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

Can i add append a date to the report html file name.  I.e today's date when the report is generated.
E.g.  so the file would be e:\report_05/05/2016.html

Thanks, Riaz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PyCharm in the top-right you can add run configurations. Click on the dropdown with configurations and select **Edit configurations...**
In the top right hit the **+**
Now under **Python tests** you can select **Nosetests**

This will create a run configuration for nosetests. Just enter the file and params you want to pas and you're good to go.

Comment: In Edit Configurations I have entered the test script file path e.g. c:\RegressionProject_TestCase2.py In Params I have entered --with-html --html-file=C:\TestReport.html  When i run it it shows the error: noserunner.py: error: no such option: --html-file

Comment: I don't think --with-html is an option nosetests has. I can't find it in the documentation (http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html). Could you try replacing those params with: --cover-html-dir=path/to/report/dir

Comment: --with-html is shown under the section Usage here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose-htmloutput

Comment: The following command works through cmd prompt: c:\python27\scripts\nosetests.exe C:\Webdriver\ClearCore Regression Test\from CC4Regression\ClearCore - Regression Test\Regression_TestCase\RegressionProject_TestCase2.py --with-html --html-file=c:\report.html